# my form is not sending after adding functions from php

Tags: php, forms

Soi tried creating a php form and it seems not to be working, it is not sending and no action is occuring. the code below is that if the HTML

```html
<form id="form" class="vbottom-desktop grid default-form no-spacing lined-form mb-xl" action="php\mail.php" method="post">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <input required type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                  <input required type="email" placeholder="Email address" name="email" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                  <textarea required placeholder="Message" name="message" class="small form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                  <input id="send" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
              </form>
```

and below this is that of the php

```html
<?php
$subject    = 'You have received this businessmail from'; 
$to         = 'okonodestine99@gmail.com'; 
$headers    = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
              'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$message    = '';

if (!empty($_POST["name"])) {
  $message .= 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . ' <br/>';
}
if (!empty($_POST["email"])) {
  $message .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . ' <br/>';
}
if (!empty($_POST["phone"])) {
  $message .= 'Phone: ' . $_POST['phone'] . ' <br/>';
}
if (!empty($_POST["website"])) {
  $message .= 'Website: ' . $_POST['website'] . ' <br/>';
}
if (!empty($_POST["message"])) {
  $message .= 'Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . ' <br/>';
}

if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
  echo 'sent';
}
else
{
  echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

any possible solution to this would be highly appreciated

Comment: _it seems not to be working_ Please explain better what is not working

Comment: When i hit the button to send,no action is taken, the mail is not sent and it stays on the page, it does not apply the functions which was called

Answer (score 0):

you should use slash not backslash in url!
try this:

```
<form id="form" class="vbottom-desktop grid default-form no-spacing lined-form mb-xl" action="php/mail.php" method="post">
                <div class="col-2">
                  <input required type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                  <input required type="email" placeholder="Email address" name="email" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                  <textarea required placeholder="Message" name="message" class="small form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                  <input id="send" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
              </form>
```

and make sure you put files like this:

```
root
|-- yourform.html(or .php whatever is that you're using)
|-- php
    |-- mail.php
```

Comment: Thank you very much, although, I tried it and it still didn't, still trying out various possible solutions

Comment: you're welcome. sorry it didn't work, tried my best!
good luck!